# How to scroll horizontally inside layout=row in angular material

Tags: angularjs, layout, scroll, flexbox, angular-material

i'm trying to make a slider with just horizontal scrollbar with cards in that, so to achieve that i'm trying to scroll the layout="row" inside with ng-repeat inside

https://codepen.io/williamscott701/pen/GmLada

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="ProductController">
  <md-content class=" md-padding " layout="column ">
    <div layout="row">
      <div flex="33" ng-repeat="y in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] ">
        <md-card>[ flex = 33 ]
        <md-card>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </md-content>
</body>
```

i dont know where it's going wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For scrolling to work you need to provide a min-width to your cards.

```
md-card {
  min-width: 200px;
}

div[layout="row"] {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

here is the link to updated codepen

https://codepen.io/vibhanshu/pen/YVMbob?editors=1100

Answer (score 2):

For a horizontal scroll you need that the content's width of an element will be greater than it's width, and for that you need to decide on a number to be the content's width. (I chose `300vw`)

**For example:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="ProductController">
  <md-content class=" md-padding " layout="column ">
    <div layout="row" style="width: 300vw;">
      <div flex ng-repeat="y in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] ">
        <md-card>[ flex = 33 ]
          <md-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</body>
```

Also note that `flex="33"` will try to place 3 elements all with `33%` of the parent's width, but because it has more than 3 they will just make them fill the width evenly, so just a `flex` directive will give you the same result.